# Is there a way to use Core with OcaIDE and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ocaml

How can I use the libraries from Core with OcaIDE and Eclipse? I am wondering if there is any way to install those libraries.

Comment: It depends on your OCaml installation. If you use windows installer -- I bet it is not possible. If you use Cygwin -- maybe. Opam doesn't work on windows. It's probably better to ask in core google group